# Como hacer una lectura del tamaño de un arreglo en c#

Tags: c#, array

se me requirio hacer un control estudiantil, con la problematica de que el usuario deba ingresar la cantidad de estudiantes y esa cantidad debe ser el tamaño limite de mi arreglo ¿como puedo hacer que el tamaño del arreglo sea variable?(estoy trabajando con whindows froms)

Comment: Tiene que ser arreglo? si en la clase se te pidió usar arreglos puedes definir la variable del arreglo sin tamaño, por ejemplo "Estudiante _estudiante[];"  y cuando requieras crear el arreglo (cuando ya tengas el límite capturado) puedes ya inicializar la variable, por ejemplo "_estudiante = new Estudiante[limite];"

Comment: @Luis Equivocado, en C#, los arrays se declaran con `Tipo[] Nombre`, utilizando el mismo ejemplo: `Estudiante[] _estudiantes;` @A_LN Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, sería de gran ayuda que nos mostraras lo que has intentado hasta ahora para poder ayudarte con precisión, tal como está tu pregunta, es demasiado amplia; por favor echale un ojo a como crear un [mcve] y luego [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/164092/edit) tu pregunta con la información necesaria, así nos ayudas a ayudarte!

Comment: @NaCI Si, fue error de dedo.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, puedes usar la clase ArrayList aunque hay mas tipos de colecciones que puedes usar para que sea mas eficiente.
[Ver información ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.120).aspx)

No obstante busca información sobre colecciones y tendrás mas información.
[Información sobre colecciones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ybcx56wz(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: ArrayList está obsoleto y no debe usarse. La alternativa es `List<T>`

Answer (score 0):

Los tamaños de los arreglos son definidos, y como buena practica, si quieres que tu lista de objetos tenga una longitud dinamica debes usar List en lugar de array

no obstante, la longitud de los arreglos puede ser modificable con

> ```
> Array.Resize(ref NombreArreglo, NuevaLongitud);
> ```

tienes que capturar desde una caja de texto de tu aplicacion la cantidad de alumnos que quieres capturar

```
 int cantidad_alumnos = int.Parse(textbox1.text);
```

luego de eso debes crear un arreglo definido :

> ```
> TipoDato[] Nombre_Variable = new Tipodato[Longitud_del_Arreglo];
> ```

asi que quedaria algo asi :

```
 string[] Alumnos = new string[cantidad_alumnos];
```

si tienes tu propia clase deberas crear el arreglo con el tipo de dato de la clase

cuando quieras calcular una nueva longitud, utiliza

```
 Array.Resize(ref Alumnos, nueva_cantidad_alumnos);
```

aunque yo preferiria utilizar listas indefinidas